# AWS Glue - how to crawl a Kinesis Firehose output folder from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have what I think should be a relatively simple use case for AWS Glue, yet I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to implement it.

I have a Kinesis Firehose job dumping streaming data into a S3 bucket. These files consist of a series of discrete web browsing events represented as JSON documents with varying structures (so, say, one document might have field 'date' but not field 'name', whereas another might have 'name' but not 'date').

I wish to run hourly ETL jobs on these files, the specifics of which are not relevant to the matter at hand.

I'm trying to run a S3 data catalog crawler and the problem I'm running into is that the Kinesis output format is not, *itself*, valid JSON, which is just baffling to me. Instead it's a bunch of JSON documents separated by a line break. The crawler can automatically identify and parse JSON files, but it cannot parse this.

I thought of writing a lambda function to 'fix' the Firehose file, triggered by its creation on the bucket, but it sounds like a cheap workaround for two pieces that *should* fit neatly together.

Another option would be just bypassing the data catalog altogether and doing the necessary transformations in the Glue script itself, but I have no idea how to get started on this.

Am I missing anything? Is there an easier way to parse Firehouse output files or, failing that, bypassing the need for a crawler?

cheers and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this; basically the problem was that not every JSON document had the same underlying structure.

I wrote a lambda script as part of the Kinesis process that forced every document into the same structure, by adding NULL fields where necessary. The crawlers were then able to correctly parse the resulting files and map them to a single table.

Comment: Can you post sample lamda function logic what you have written that forced every document into the same structure ?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're describing the behaviour of Kinesis Firehose, which is to concatenate multiple incoming records according to some buffering (time and size) settings, and then write the records to S3 as a single object. [Firehose Data Delivery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/basic-deliver.html#format)

The batching of multiple records into a single file is important if the workload will contain a large number of records, as performance (and S3 costs) for processing many small files from S3 can be less than optimal.

AWS Glue Crawlers and ETL jobs do support processing of 'JSON line' ([newline delimited JSON](http://jsonlines.org/)) format.

If the crawler is failing to run please include the logs or error details (and if possible the crawler run duration, and number of tables created and updated.

I have seen a crawler fail in an instance where differences in the files being crawled forced it into a table-per-file mode, and it hit a limit on the number of tables. [AWS Glue Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/troubleshooting-service-limits.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste few lines from the json file the firehose creating? I ran the crawler on json file generated by Kinesis Streams and it was able to parse it successfully.

Did you also try "convert record format" when you create the Firehose job? There you can specify the JSONSerDe or Glue catalog to parse your data.

Answer (score 0):

What solved this for me was to add a newline field '/n' to end of each payload sent to firehose.

```
msg_pkg = (str(json_response) + '\n').encode('utf-8')
record = {'Data': msg_pkg}
put_firehose('agg2-na-firehose', record
```

Because apparently the Hive JSON SerDe is the default used to proces json data. After doing this I was able to crawl the json data and read it in Athena as well.